# Python (if, elif, else) working with timestamp

Tags: python, timestamp, strftime

I am taking a beginning Python programming class and I am having trouble getting the code below to work correctly.  The assignment asks: write a Python code that uses the “strftime()” function to get the today’s weekday value and then use an “if..elif..else” statement to display the associated message.  So, with today being Friday (w == 5) for me, it should print "Prevention is better than cure."  Instead, it keeps printing the else statement "Stupid is as stupid does."  Advice?

```
import datetime

t = datetime.date.today()
w = t.strftime("%w"); # day of week

if (w == 0): print("The devil looks after his own.");
elif (w == 1): print("Everything comes to him who waits.");
elif (w == 2): print("Give credit where credit is due.");
elif (w == 3): print("If you pay peanuts, you get monkeys.");
elif (w == 4): print("Money makes the world go round.");
elif (w == 5): print("Prevention is better than cure.");
else: print("Stupid is as stupid does.");
```

Comment: `w` is a string, `'5'`. you can't compare that to an int; they're never equal

Comment: Python doesn't need `;` semicolons; you may want to drop those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `strftime()`, which returns a `str`, use `weekday()`, which returns an `int`:

```
t = datetime.date.today()
w = today.weekday() + 1  # +1 because weekday() is 0-based, %w is 1-based
```

In Python, a string and a number are never equal.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.  I used `today = datetime.date.today() w = today.weekday() + 1` and everything works as expected now.

Comment: No need to use `+ 1` here, and the OP could use a list of texts instead all those `if` statements.

Comment: the +1 was necessary to match the existing string value. list of texts seems presumptive if OP would eventually do more than just print strings